# How to display same city name in all JSP pages in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am working on an ecommerce web application in Spring Boot. I have city name that needs to be displayed in all JSP pages. For example, If I choose city name as Mumbai, then whatever be the number of JSP pages is there (excluding checkout page) same city name should be displayed (i.e. Mumbai should be displayed in all pages except checkout page). So, I tried to get this thing done with the use of query parameter. But unable to display same city name in another pages ( if I click on some other links to redirect to another page).

From below script, I get city name from query parameter from index.jsp and displayed it in webheader.jsp.

```
    function getcities(){
                var city = document.getElementById('cityname').value;
                var url = "api/getcities";
                $.post(url, {
                    city : city,
                }, function(data, status) {
                    if (data.status == "OK") {
                        if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                            var citylist = data.response;
                            var citylistlen = citylist.length;
                            var city = ""; 
                            if(citylistlen > 0){
                                for(var i = 0; i < citylistlen; i++){
                                    var pincode = citylist[i].pincode;
                                    var cityname = citylist[i].delivercityid.city;
                                    if(null != pincode && null != cityname){
                                        city = city + "<div style='border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; display: block; z-index: 100;  position: inherit; font-style: oblique; color: blueviolet;' onclick=\"getcitydata('"+citylist[i].delivercityid.delivercityid+"','"+cityname+"')\">"
                                        +"<div><div style='padding: 5px;'><a href=\"..<%=WebUrl.index%>?city="+cityname+"\"><strong style=\"color: indigo;\">"+cityname+"</strong>&nbsp;("+pincode+")</a></div></div></div>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            document.getElementById('showcity').innerHTML = city;
                        } else {
                            var error = data.responseMessage;
                            swal(error, "", "error");
                        }
                    } else {
                        var error = data.responseMessage;
                        swal(error, "", "error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Inside webheader.jsp:

```
    <div class="city-popup">
            <div id="user-selected-city-input">
                <h6>Delivery In</h6>
                    <%
                        String cityname = request.getParameter("city"); 
                        if(cityname == null){
                         out.print("<h6 style=\"color: #330000;\">Choose City</h6>");
                        }else{
                         out.print("<h5 style=\"color: #330000;\">"+cityname+"</h5>");
                        }
                    %>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What and how should it done? Do I need to use cookies or something else to do so?

[image: Picked some city name]

[image: Screenshot to show other JSP page]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session.setAttribute("city",cname)` then you can access by session.getAttribute()

Comment: I tried this way too, but it did not worked.

Comment: You setting within <% %>

Comment: Can you check value null or not before setting to session.

Comment: I tried String city = request.getParameter("city"); session.setAttribute("cityname", city); inside webheader.jsp and getAttribute inside product.jsp as String city = (String)session.getAttribute("cityname");
 System.out.println("City name from previous JSP: "+city.toString()); So it printed city name. But unable to display that name inside that div.

Comment: Basically, webheader page is common for all other JSP pages. I used to include using <jsp:include file="webheader.jsp"></jsp:include>

Comment: <p><% out.print( session.getId()); %><p>

Comment: <p><% out.print( session.getAttribute("cityname")):%><p>

Comment: Try as above one

Comment: No, it did not worked. Again it is showing choose city but not city name.

Comment: You said you able to print the city name in product.jsp right.

Comment: <p><% out.print(city); %></p>

Comment: If not work above one then pass value as hidden value.  <input type = "hidden" name = "city" value = city>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234715/discussion-between-rakhi-sharma-and-selvakumar-anushan).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for interceptors. Interceptor can intercept any request and you can easily inject something into the request or modify the request to suit your need.

In your case, you can filter the requests in the interceptor and only pass the city as a JSP object through the `postHandle` method of `HandlerInterceptor` when the request URL doesn't contain the checkout page link.

Check out this [page](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) for more info about `HandlerInerceptor`.

Comment: I am not sure about HandlerInterceptor thing. First, need to understand this thing then only would be able to implement. Thank you.